# Python - Grouping keys having similar values in a dictionary

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, grouping

I have a database of hotels stored in MongoDB. My aim is to group together the hotels which have intersecting phone numbers.

> **Example** : If Hotel A has phone numbers 1,2; B has phone numbers 2,3; C has phone numbers 3,4; D has phone numbers 5,6; E has phone numbers 6,7, then A, B, C will be grouped together and D, E will be put in another group so that when a user searches for Hotel A, he'll get Hotels B and C as recommended hotels.

The structure of document in my database is :

> {
>   "_id" : ObjectId("57bd5108f4733211b61217fa"),
>   "autoid" : 1,
>   "parentid" : "P01982.01982.110601173548.N2C5",
>   "companyname" : "Sheldan Holiday Home",
>   "latitude" : 34.169552,
>   "longitude" : 77.579315,
>   "state" : "JAMMU AND KASHMIR",
>   "city" : "LEH Ladakh",
>   "pincode" : 194101,
>   "phone_search" : "9419179870|253013",
>   "address" : "Sheldan Holiday Home|Changspa|Leh Ladakh-194101|LEH Ladakh|JAMMU
>   AND KASHMIR",
>   "email" : "",
>   "website" : "",
>     "national_catidlineage_search" : "/10255012/|/10255031/|/10255037/|/10238369/|/10238380/|/10238373/",
>     "area" : "Leh Ladakh",
>   "data_city" : "Leh Ladakh"}

**What I've accomplished till now:**
I've been able to split the phone numbers and store the "parentid" of hotels in a dictionary grouped by "phone_search"

> **Example** : u'9426029957': [u'P2772.2772.140207213142.C6X5'], u'9796603277': [u'P1991.1991.110710093157.Z8G1'], u'9447706927':
>   [u'PX477.X477.160620184114.P7P3', u'PX484.X484.160620185334.E4G6'] and
>   so on...

**What I'm planning to do :** I'm planning on assigning a group id to hotels which are related. So in the above example, Hotels A, B, C will be given group id 1 and D, E will be assigned group id 2.

But I'm stuck on how to achieve it **efficiently**.

Here's the code which I've written up till now. Any other suggestions are welcome, too.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient #To import client for MongoDB
from pprint import pprint #Pretty print 

#Defining variables
hotels = []
hotelsByPhone = {}
phones = []

#Initializing MongoDB client
client = MongoClient()

#Connection
db = client.hotel
collection = db.hotelData

#Storing all hotels in a list 'hotels'
for post in collection.find():
    hotels.append(post)

#Splitting all the numbers and storing parent ids of hotels grouped together by similar phone numbers
for hotel in hotels:
    try:
        phones = hotel["phone_search"].split("|")
        for phone in phones:
            hotelsByPhone.setdefault(phone,[]).append(hotel["parentid"])
    except:
        try:
            phones = hotel["phone_search"]
            hotelsByPhone.setdefault(phones,[]).append(hotel["parentid"])
        except:
            hotelsByPhone.setdefault(phones,[]).append(hotel["parentid"])
```

Comment: What does the second `except` do? I'm quite sure the first could be removed if you change `phones = hotel["phone_search"].split("|")` to `phones = list(hotel["phone_search"].split("|"))`. Apart from that, I think you're going to have to do something more sophisticated to group hotels, as you will occasionally have to merge groups if you discover a link.

Comment: @KeithWM Thanks for your suggestion. I'll surely look into it. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "something more sophisticated"? How do I go about it?

Comment: One important (and somewhat pedagogical) question: if a hotel F turns up with phone numbers 1 and 7, do you want to then make A, B, C, D, E and F into one big group? It seems to me all your current approach does is invert the relationship between hotels and phone numbers. In other words, you get a list of hotels for each phone number.

Comment: @KeithWM Yes. In theory, if a new hotel like F turns up, all the above-mentioned hotels will be required to be group together. Can you recommend any other approach which can solve this problem?

Comment: @KeithWM Just one question. Do you think using networkX would be a better option?

Comment: I think you will most likely be better off using some form of network tool, that way you can also get a more refined measure of similarity between hotels.